# What are the side effects of using Apache Kafka a a key/value store?

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-computing, latency

I know Kafka is not a k/v store, but bear with me. Suppose that it's roughly implemented using the k/v API below. Each key is a topic, and the current "value" of the key is the last message written to the topic:

```
put(key, value) --> publish(topic=key, message=value)
get(key) --> consume(topic=key, offset = last_offset - 1)
```

Furthermore, suppose that the state is replicated between different Kafka clusters (using MirrorMaker bidirectionally), as to allow users to read/write to closer datacenter to reduce latency.

I already know some of the obvious side effects of doing this, For instance:

- Since a "key" maps to a topic, you can only have 1 partition in order to guarantee ordering (because you want the last value *put* to always be at the end of the log).
- The retention policy needs to be considered, because the last message in the log could be deleted
- If you do a put(key, value) to the cluster closest to you, even though that is technically the most recent *put* on that key, MirrorMaker (due to latency) may publish an outdated key from another cluster, overwriting your most recent put value

The main concerns here are latency, especially between different clusters. How do you think this solution holds up under a stressful workload (say, thousands of writes / second on a given key / topic), and stressful network conditions, compared to a tradition k/v solution such as Redis, memcached or etcd?

Thoughts?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4):

Kafka can works as an KV event store, actually there is an improvement already implemented: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-67%3A+Queryable+state+for+Kafka+Streams

And here are a couple of links with more examples of how to use Kafka Streams to query the state stored in Kafka: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/03/interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka-streams/, https://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/

It uses RocksDB by default but is pluggable: https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/

You will have to think about how to manage the storage at the application level, but essentially, your concerns are managed by Kafka Streams API.

Hope this helps.